# How is BERT Layer sequence output used?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am reading [this Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/gunesevitan/nlp-with-disaster-tweets-eda-cleaning-and-bert).

In the class DisasterDetector, in build_model(), `clf_output = sequence_output[:, 0, :]`
. A sigmoid activation is then applied in order to generate the model output.

The location the BertLayer was obtained from on [tfhub](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1) describes the shape of sequence_output as `[batch_size, max_seq_length, 768]`. Why are we choosing only the first index over the max_seq_length dimension (indexing a 0)? If this corresponds to only the first token in the output sequence, and not the other tokens, why is this used in the binary classification task?

Answer (score 0):

the first token of output sequence is from the first of input ，i e. [CLS].
the [CLS] is regarded as the represition of the whole input sequence.
u can read the original paper to understand it better.